# How to output only blockquotes content from recent posts in a widget?

Tags: widgets, recent-posts

I created a simple widget that displays recent post titles. How can I only display the content that is between < blockquote >< /blockquote > from recent posts?

For example, all my posts have a blockquote html tag like this:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

< blockquote >***Blockquote content***< /blockquote >

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."

Basically I need to display recent posts like this:

---

**Recent posts widget title**

**Post title 1**

Blockquote content from post

**Post title 2**

Blockquote content from post

**Post title 3**

Blockquote content from post

Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179423/targeting-and-posting-block-quotes-from-posts

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

```
$html = str_get_html(the_content());
$blockquote = $html->find('blockquote', 0);
echo $blockquote
```